# Perform method after select variable assignments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment, dry

I'm trying to DRY up some code, and I feel like Ruby's variable assignment must provide a way to simplify this. I have a class with a number of different instance variables defined. Some of these are intended to be hidden (or read-only), but many are public, with read/write access.

For all of the variables with public write-access, I want to perform a certain method after each assignment. I know that, in general, I can do this:

```
def foo=(new_foo)
    @foo = new_foo
    post_process(@foo)
end

def bar=(new_bar)
    @bar = new_bar
    post_process(@foo)
end
```

However, it seems that there should be a nice way to DRY this up, since I'm doing essentially the same thing after each assignment (ie, running the same method, and passing the newly-assigned variable as a parameter to that method). Since I have a number of such variables, it would be great to have a general-purpose solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Simpler solution

If you assign those variables in batch, you can do something like this:

```
kv_pairs = {:foo => new_foo_value,
  :bar => new_bar_value}

kv_pairs.each do |k, v|
  self.send(k.to_s + '=', v)
  post_process(v)
end
```

#### Metaprogramming

Here's some ruby magic :-)

```
module PostProcessAssignments
  def hooked_accessor( *symbols )
    symbols.each { | symbol |
      class_eval( "def #{symbol}() @#{symbol}; end" )
      class_eval( "def #{symbol}=(val) @#{symbol} = val; post_process('#{symbol}', val); end" )
    }
  end
end

class MyClass
  extend PostProcessAssignments

  hooked_accessor :foo

  def post_process prop, val
    puts "#{prop} was set to #{val}"
  end


end

mc = MyClass.new
mc.foo = 4
puts mc.foo
```

Outputs:

```
foo was set to 4
4
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't count on those variables being reassigned together, so it'd be nice to allow for people to do my_var.foo = new_value directly. That said, this gives me an idea - maybe there's a way to overload the '=' method of all the relevant variables simultaneously and then using .to_s to handle the assignment. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about (meta)programming in Ruby to do this exactly.

Comment: Hah, yeah, I think our edits crossed. That looks pretty slick. The hooked_accessor :foo line still confuses me, though. How does mc.foo know to call hooked_accessor at the right time? Is it just analogous to the way attr_accessor :foo is called?

Comment: Also, are there any security problems with using class_eval in Ruby?

Comment: Use `hooked_accessor` as a drop-in replacement for `attr_accessor`. Security problems? Don't think so. Some name clashing is probable, but it's trivial to avoid.